# PayPal Orders Create: Status 422, amount mismatch error despite matching values

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am receiving a 422 `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` error from paypal, indicating that my `amount->value` and `breakdown` values don't match up, but as far as I can tell they aren't. The request body is as follows:

```
"amount": {
  "currency_code": "USD",
  "value": 5,
  "breakdown": {
    "item_total": {
      "value": 10,
      "currency_code": "USD",
      "discount": {
        "value": 5,
        "currency_code": "USD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error message says about `amount->value`: `Should equal item_total + tax_total + shipping + handling + insurance - shipping_discount - discount.`

Since I don't have shipping/handling/insurance/etc, shouldn't it just be `5(amount) = 10(item_total) - 5(discount)`? What am I missing here?

Also, just in case it matters, I have just a single item in the purchase unit:

```
"items": [
  {
    "name": "...",
    "unit_amount": {
      "value": 10,
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "category": "DIGITAL_GOODS"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discount` is in the [wrong place](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown) here:

> ```
> "breakdown": {
>    "item_total": {
>      "value": 10,
>      "currency_code": "USD",
>      "discount": {
>        "value": 5,
>        "currency_code": "USD"
>      }
>    }
>  }
> ```

Move it out of `item_total` (where it's being ignored as an unknown field), and into the parent `breakdown` object where it belongs.

Comment: Ah, of course. Been looking at this for too long, needed some fresh eyes i guess. Thanks

Comment: and how to add tax

Answer (score -1):

For PHP that would be :

```
$request->body = [
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'purchase_units' => [
            [
                'invoice_id' => 'some-id',
                'amount' => [
                    'value' => 15,
                    'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                    'breakdown' => [
                        'shipping' => [
                            'value' => 5,
                            'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                        ],
                        'item_total' => [
                            'value' => 10,
                            'currency_code' => 'EUR',
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'application_context' => [
            'cancel_url' => $cancelUrl,
            'return_url' => $returnUrl,
        ],
    ];
```